# How to pivot a dataframe into a square dataframe with number of intersections in other column as values

Tags: python, pandas

How to pivot a dataframe into a square dataframe with number of intersections in value column as values where

my input dataframe is

```
field    value
a          1
a          2
b          3
b          1
c          2
c          5
```

Output should be

```
  a b c
a 2 1 1
b 1 2 0
c 1 0 2
```

The values in the output data frame should be the number of intersection of values in the value column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cross join with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = df.merge(df, on='value')
df = pd.crosstab(df['field_x'], df['field_y'])
print (df)

field_y  a  b  c
field_x         
a        2  1  1
b        1  2  0
c        1  0  2
```

Then remove index and columns names by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
df = pd.crosstab(df['field_x'], df['field_y']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
   a  b  c
a  2  1  1
b  1  2  0
c  1  0  2

#pandas bellow
df = pd.crosstab(df['field_x'], df['field_y']).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```